# Displaying data in template

Tags: django

Hello guys i cannot display this data on my template i have tried few methods but failed is there any solution

views.py

```
def list_page(request):
    qs = Add.objects.annotate(month=TruncDate('date')
    ).values('month').annotate(
    total_income=Sum('budget'),
    total_expense=Sum('expense')
    ).order_by('date')
    for i in qs:
        print (i['month'],)
    x = {'qs':qs,}
    return render(request, 'list_page.html', x)
```

printing only in console and not clearly printing in template.

Comment: add your template code

Comment: Template is simple i have tried     {% for i in qs %} {{i.month}} {% endfor %} not working

Comment: in console its pretty clear  with this code print (i['month],)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You render it the same way:

```
{% for row in qs %}
    {{ row.month|date:'F Y' }}: {{ row.total_income }} / {{ row.total_expense }}
{% endfor %}
```

Of course the above is just a sketch, and you probably should alter it to render it more conveniently.

Comment: Thanks once again .. Mr.willem can you tell me from where did you learn django .

Comment: @MuhammedBilal: mainly through some colleagues (with [Sjoerd-Job Postmus](https://twitter.com/sjoerdjob) as TLD), so I'm afraid that will not help you much :s.